# Simplify $\arccos{\sqrt{ 2\over 3}}−\arccos{\frac{\sqrt6+1}{2\sqrt3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

---

> Prove $$\arccos{\sqrt{ 2\over 3}}−\arccos{\dfrac{\sqrt6+1}{2\sqrt3}} = \dfrac\pi6$$

How to proceed with this question? I have tried changing them to $\arctan$ and applying $\arctan a- \arctan b$ but ended up getting some numbers which cant be simplied further.

Comment: Is the task to simplify the expression? Please type it again on the body of the question with MathJax, in order to make the question more understandable.

Comment: @MattiP. We have to prove that the expression is qual to π/6

Comment: @MattiP. Sorry about that i dun know to type in mathjax

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user568101 There are tutorials in ? -> Help center -> Our model -> How can I format mathematics here?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\sqrt6+1}{2\sqrt3}$$

$$=\sqrt{\dfrac23}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt3}2+\sqrt{\dfrac13}\cdot\dfrac12$$

$$=\cos\left(\dfrac\pi6-\arccos\sqrt{\dfrac23}\right)=?$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Answer (score 3):

Let $$\alpha = \arccos{\sqrt2\over \sqrt3}\;\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\;\beta =\arccos{\sqrt6+1\over 2\sqrt3}$$

so $$ \cos \alpha = \sqrt{2\over 3}\;\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\;\cos \beta = {\sqrt{6}+1\over 2\sqrt{3}}$$

and 
 $$ \sin \alpha = \sqrt{1-{2\over 3}} ={1\over \sqrt{3}}\;\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;\;\sin \beta = \sqrt{1-{7+2\sqrt{6}\over 12}} = \sqrt{{5-2\sqrt{6}\over 12}}$$

so $$\cos (\alpha -\beta) = \sqrt{2\over 3} {\sqrt{6}+1\over 2\sqrt{3}}+{1\over \sqrt{3}}\sqrt{{5-2\sqrt{6}\over 12}}=$$

$$ = {\sqrt{12}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}\over 6} $$

$$ = {2\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^2}\over 6} $$

$$ = {\sqrt{3}\over 2} $$

so $\alpha -\beta = \pi/6$

Comment: Nice! Just in case OP is interested, another alternative could be to use $\arccos(\alpha) - \arccos(\beta) = \arccos\left(\alpha\beta + \sqrt{(1 - \alpha)^2(1 - \beta)^2}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that $\cos(\text{your expression})$ simplifies to what it should.
Then show that your expression is in the correct interval.